# Any way to recover lost items?

Tags: pokemon-go

I kinda accidentally discarded an incense while searching for Pokemon. Is there any way I can recover my incense without having to pay, or is it lost for good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you discard an item there is no way to get it back.